# Building Dependent Projects in Two Different Repos

Tags: dependencies, repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

I tried to build a project B which is dependent on project A through Bitbucket Pipelines. Both are in different repositories in Bitbucket. When i tried to Build project B, I am getting an errror like missing dependency A.jar file. Is there any solution for this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post the bitbucket-pipelines.yml (or at least a cleaned-up version) for project B? That may make it easier to tell where the problem is.

Comment: I am facing same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504651/how-to-build-dependent-projects-using-bit-bucket-pipeline . It seems that each pipeline is being run on separate docker images. Because of this maven local repo is different for both the projects. Uploading the artifact to a remote repo and referencing the dependency from remote repo seems to be only solution..  Any thoughts?