# How to build dependent projects using Bit Bucket pipeline

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to get my build working with  pipeline using maven . I have two bit bucket repositories for  two maven projects.  repository1 -> project1  repository2 -> project2.   project2 has dependency on project1.  Now I dont have problem in building project1 as it doesn't has dependency on any projects. But when I try to build project2 using pipeline build is failing because maven is not finding the project1 artifact.

I got to know that every pipeline runs within a docker image. So my guess is that pipelines for project1 and project2 are running in 2 separate docker images. Because of this when I run pipeline for project2 maven is not finding project1 artifact in local repository. One way to fix this is hosting a maven remote repo for my project artifacts and adding the repo in POM of project2. But i don't want to host a maven repo. I want maven to pick the artifact from local repo. How to get this working?

Comment: Are you using a repository manager where you distribute your build artifacts like the ones you have created by building project1 ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry I am new to bitbucket. I am not sure what is 'repository manager'  you are talking about. Can you please elaboreate. My problem is my two projects are in 2 separte repos.  So when project2 pipeline tries to build it don't have project1 artifact dependency. My generated artiffacts are stored on local repo only

Comment: Are building on bitbucket itself or in house of a company or just private?

Comment: Its a private repo which I am trying to build on bitbucket

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry that no one ever answered this question for you. Setting up BitBucket Pipelines to use private maven repositories requires you to create a custom settings.xml file in the pipeline and then invoking maven with that file specified.

You can't just put a settings.xml file in your source code repository as it would put your credentials at risk. Instead, you can create a settings.xml file and set credentials from BitBucket Pipelines Secure environment variables.

It's pretty straightforward once you see it in action.  I actually wrote an [extensive guide on how to completely setup BitBucket Pipelines with Maven repositories](https://www.cloudrepo.io/articles/continuous-integration-a-complete-guide-to-bitbucket-pipelines-with-maven-repositories.html) that shows specifically how to do this in a secure manner.

Comment: Thanks for the response I will try this and let you know. Just to be sure again does this solution works if I dont have any private artifact repo? So that dependent artifacts will be picked from local .m2/repository folder?

Comment: My requirement is Project1 will be built first and stored into .m2/repository  folder. When project2 starts building it should pick project1 dependency from ./m2/repository as we dont have a company wide repository